# asp.net| change the place webforms save user data

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to change the place my webform saves the data.

What I mean is, when you open a Visual Stuido/C# Web App, its has a user login/register data.

The default data is saved in your project folder, in APP_DATA as: `ASPNETDB.MDF`.

What about if I want to use MSSQL Server 2008R2.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup a new database and change your `connectionstring` in the `web.config`:

[Using SQL Server instead of ASPNETDB.mdf](http://www.studiocoast.com.au/knowledgebase/6/aspnet/using-sql-server-instead-of-aspnetdbmdf.aspx)

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

[How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean? Yes changing your connectionstring to another database always works as long as you have the right connection information.

Comment: i will give it a try and answer here

Comment: Dont work, Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'. ASP.NET .. <>

Comment: You also need to run the aspnet_regsql.exe tool: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx  This is covered in the first item in the first link on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

in really server MS Server 2008R2 you must doing backup from your "home" datafiles: "in APP_DATA as :ASPNETDB.MDF"
p.s. sorry for my bad English.